# Which Lebesgue theorem to use

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $p > 0$ be fixed. For $t > 0$ and $x\in[0,1]$ define $$f(t,x) = \frac{1}{t}x^pe^{-\frac{x}{t}}.$$
For each values of $p$ does each of the following statement hold true?

(a) $f_t \rightarrow 0$ a.e. as $t \rightarrow 0$.

(b) $f_t \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

(c) $\int_0^1f_t(x)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Answers:

(a) Notice that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}f_t(x)$ yields an indeterminate form $0/0$. Thus using L'Hopital rule we have $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}x^pe^{-\frac{x}{t}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}-x^{p+1}e^{-x/t} = -x^{p+1}/\infty = 0.$$And this holds for all $p > 0$ on $[0,1] \setminus \{x = 0\}$ otherwise we keep getting indeterminate forms.

(b) To see uniform convergence we start with $$\left|f_t(x)\right|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\frac{1}{t}x^pe^{-\frac{x}{t}}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{x}{t}}\right|,$$and as $t \rightarrow 0$ we get $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\|f_t(x)\|_\infty = 0$. Observe that if $x = 0$ when taking the supremum then we trivially get $0$ as the limit.

(c) Now I am having some troubles satisfying the conditions of the Lebesgue theorem to get the integral over $0$ as to yield the result.

I have seen several variations of the Lebesgue theorem.

(i) Classical;
(ii) If $f_t(x)$ is bounded below for each $x$ and $f_t \uparrow f$;
(iii) if $|f_t(x)| \leq M$, where $M$ is some constant, for all $x$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$.

I think the main problem is showing that I can bound $|f(x,t)|$ with some non-negative function $g(x)$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Missing context? Do you only consider $f$ as defined over $(0,\infty)\times[0,1]$?

Comment: @FShrike, yes I am sorry, $f(t,x)$ is defined on $(0,\infty) \times [0,1]$

Comment: I don't have an answer yet but, just saying: although (a) is correct you have misapplied LH rule, you forget that the derivative of $e^{-x/t}$ in $t$ is $\color{red}{(1/t^2)}\cdot(-xe^{-x/t})$ and it is *not* an indeterminate form at $x=0$ since the function is there defined as zero for all $t$-values and (b) is very suspicious; your bound on the RHS is not actually uniform (it depends on $x$) and (!) there is a problem at $x=0$; although, trivially, $f_t(0)=0$ always your current method does not show convergence is uniform in neighbourhoods of zero. Your answer should depend on $p$, perhaps

Comment: And for $(c)$: if we really do have uniform convergence, then it's a standard theorem of (Riemann but also Lebesgue) integration that this suffices to take the limit under the integral sign (for finite measure spaces, mind. Not sure about general case)

Comment: Thanks for the help @FShrike.

Comment: $$F(t)=\int_0^1f_t(x)\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}x^pe^{-\frac xt}\,dx$$
$u=\frac xt\rightarrow dx=t\,du$
$$F(t)=\int_0^{1/t}(ut)^pe^{-u}\,du=t^p\int_0^{1/t}u^pe^{-u}\,du\le t^p\left[\frac{u^{p+1}}{p+1}\right]_0^{1/t}=\frac{t^pt^{-(p+1)}}{p+1}=\frac{1}{t(p+1)}$$
However this is not a tight bound for small $t$. Notice that as $t\to0^+$ the integral becomes $\Gamma(p+1)$ as the integral is effectively a form of the **upper incomplete gamma function**.